# Number of local maxima in MAX-2-SAT

Tags: co.combinatorics, max2sat

Given an instance of MAX-2-SAT, let us call an assignment of variables a "local maximum" if changing the value of any variable reduces the number of satisfied clauses.  My question is, how many local maxima can an instance of MAX-2-SAT have?  Clearly it must be less than $2^N$, but how large can it be?

To illustrate, suppose instead of considering MAX-2-SAT, we considered MAX-k-CSP with $k=N$ and a single clause.  This means that we can choose any function of $N$ variables as the truth value of the clause.  If we pick, for example, the parity function so that the clause is true if parity is odd, then there are $2^{N-1}$ local maxima (any odd parity configuration is a local maximum as flipping any spin makes it even parity).  On the other hand, I would guess that going from MAX-k-CSP to MAX-2-SAT will significantly reduce the maximum possible number of local maxima.

I would also be interested if anyone knows the answer to the number of local maximum for MAX-k-SAT and MAX-k-CSP for $k>2$ but $k=O(1)$.  I would also be interested in the answer in the case of bounded ratio of number of clauses to number of variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can get a $n \choose n/2$ lower bound by considering the $n$ variable formula that for every pair $x$, $y$, of variables contains the clauses $(x \vee y)$ and $(\neg x \vee \neg y)$. The total number of clauses is $2 \cdot {n \choose 2}$. Every assignment will satisfy one of the two clauses on $x$ and $y$. Both clauses are satisfied exactly when $x$ and $y$ get different values. Hence, if $i$ variables are set to true the total number of satisfied clauses is
$${n \choose 2} + i \cdot (n-i).$$
This is maximized when $i = n/2$. Thus, for even $n$, every assignment that sets exactly $n/2$ variables to true is a local maxima. The total number of such assignments is $n \choose n/2$, which is $\Theta(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}})$.

Comment: Note that this is precisely the parity argument given in the original question (albeit clearly spelled out in the 2-SAT case and fully analyzed) :).

Comment: In this case, aren't the described assignments actually also *global* maxima? But I suppose if you set $i=n/2 \pm 1$, then you will get the same asymptotic bound but have local maxima that are not globally maximum.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment... But yes I am sure one can add some constant size gadgets to have roughly as many local maxima that are not global maxima.

Comment: I see what you mean about my second comment - that doesn't really work. But I agree one should be able to add some small gadgets to make local but non-global maxima.